# Oracle Connect By vs Recursive User-Defined Function performance

Tags: oracle, recursion, connect-by

I'm doing a basic performance check using both Connect By and a user-defined function to get a parent value. It seems that using a user-defined function performs better than the Connect By query.

I would like to know if using the user-defined function is supposed to be better performing as compared to Connect By.

```
create table org ( pid number, cid number, type varchar2(10), name varchar2(30) );

alter table org add constraint org_pk primary key ( cid ); -- UPDATE#2

insert into org values (null,1,'MGT','OP');
insert into org values (1,2,'DEP','HR');
insert into org values (1,3,'DEP','IT');
insert into org values (3,4,'DIV','WEB');
insert into org values (3,5,'DIV','DB');
insert into org values (4,6,'SEC','HTML');
insert into org values (4,7,'SEC','JAVA');

create or replace function get_dep ( p_cid in number ) return number
is
  l_pid number;
  l_cid number;
  l_type varchar2(30);
begin
  select pid
       , cid
       , type
    into l_pid
       , l_cid
       , l_type
    from org
   where cid = p_cid;

  if ( l_type = 'MGT' ) then
    return null;
  elsif ( l_type = 'DEP' ) then
    return l_cid;
  else
    return get_dep ( l_pid );
  end if;
end;
/

 select cid --correction
   from org
  where type = 'DEP'
  start
   with cid = 7
connect
     by
  prior pid = cid
    and
  prior type != 'DEP'


-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                         |      |     2 |    66 |     6  (17)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  FILTER                                  |      |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   CONNECT BY NO FILTERING WITH START-WITH|      |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL                     | ORG  |     7 |   231 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 select get_dep ( cid )
   from org
  where cid = 7;

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |     1 |    13 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| ORG  |     1 |    13 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**UPDATE #1:**
I updated the function to add a logic to return null if id is MGT.

Also, change the queries to fetch all records in the table.

```
 select cid, ( select cid
                 from org
                where type = 'DEP'
                start
                 with cid = m.cid
              connect
                   by
                prior pid = cid
                  and
                prior type != 'DEP' ) dep
  from org m;

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                         |      |     7 |    91 |    10   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  FILTER                                  |      |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   CONNECT BY NO FILTERING WITH START-WITH|      |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL                     | ORG  |     7 |   231 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL                       | ORG  |     7 |    91 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 select cid, get_dep ( cid ) dep
   from org;


--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |     7 |    91 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| ORG  |     7 |    91 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**UPDATE #2**: Added index as suggested. The explain plan improved on both but the query with the user-defined function still performs better based on the explain plan (unless I'm not interpreting the plan correctly).

```
 select cid, ( select cid
                 from org
                where type = 'DEP'
                start
                 with cid = m.cid
              connect
                   by
                prior pid = cid
                  and
                prior type != 'DEP' ) dep
  from org m;

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                      | Name   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT               |        |     7 |    91 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  FILTER                        |        |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   CONNECT BY WITH FILTERING    |        |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | ORG    |     1 |    33 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN          | ORG_PK |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |    NESTED LOOPS                |        |     1 |    53 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |     CONNECT BY PUMP            |        |       |       |            |          |
|   7 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| ORG    |     1 |    33 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  8 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | ORG_PK |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   9 |  INDEX FULL SCAN               | ORG_PK |     7 |    91 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 select cid, get_dep ( cid ) dep
   from org;

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |        |     7 |    91 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  INDEX FULL SCAN | ORG_PK |     7 |    91 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Why are you comparing this for a single row? Run it for a large dataset and you would know the difference.

Comment: Updated my question with more info. Changed the queries the same way I'm using it in my actual table which has 500 records more or less. Running the query using the Connect By takes a lot longer as compared to using the user-defined function.

Comment: You should definitively define an index on the `cid` column. Without it you compare two *bad* access plans.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber added index as suggested but still the query with user-defined function out performs the one with connect by,

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in your example, SQL and PL/SQL return different results.

```
SQL>  select pid
  2     from org
  3    where type = 'DEP'
  4    start
  5     with cid = 7
  6  connect
  7       by
  8    prior pid = cid
  9      and
 10    prior type != 'DEP';

       PID
----------
         1

SQL>
SQL>  select get_dep ( cid )
  2     from org
  3    where cid = 7;

GET_DEP(CID)
------------
           3
```

Secondly, it does not really make sense to compare different approaches on such **extremely small data volumes**.

Let's assume we have a tree with depth 999 999 and want to find a root for a given node.
In my example there is only one tree (which is actually a list since each parent has one child) therefore root is the same for all nodes.
The important thing is: **the bigger depth of a given ID the longer execution time**.

```
create table org0 ( pid number, cid number, name varchar2(30) );

insert into org0
select rownum, rownum+1, 'name' || rpad(rownum,25,'#')
from dual
connect by rownum < 1e6;

alter table org0 add constraint org0_pk primary key ( cid );
```

Function for returning the root

```
create or replace function get_id(p_cid in number) return number is
  l_pid number;
begin
  select pid into l_pid from org0 where cid = p_cid;
  return get_id(l_pid);
exception
  when no_data_found then
    return p_cid;
end get_id;
/
```

Testing

**SQL**

```
SQL> select pid id
  2    from org0
  3   where connect_by_isleaf = 1
  4   start with cid = 10000
  5  connect by prior pid = cid;

        ID
----------
         1

Elapsed: 00:00:00.07
SQL>
SQL> select pid id
  2    from org0
  3   where connect_by_isleaf = 1
  4   start with cid = 100000
  5  connect by prior pid = cid;

        ID
----------
         1

Elapsed: 00:00:00.55
SQL>
SQL> select pid id
  2    from org0
  3   where connect_by_isleaf = 1
  4   start with cid = 1000000
  5  connect by prior pid = cid;

        ID
----------
         1

Elapsed: 00:00:05.79
```

**PL/SQL**

```
SQL> select get_id(10000) id from dual;

        ID
----------
         1

Elapsed: 00:00:00.15
SQL> select get_id(100000) id from dual;

        ID
----------
         1

Elapsed: 00:00:01.47
SQL> select get_id(1000000) id from dual;

        ID
----------
         1

Elapsed: 00:00:14.83
```

As you can see, PL/SQL is approximately 2 times slower.

In some specific cases PL/SQL may be faster though (not for your task).
You can read about fine grained performance analysis and using tools like dbms_hprof in this book [Oracle SQL Revealed](https://www.apress.com/gb/book/9781484233719), chapter "When PL/SQL Is Better Than Vanilla SQL".

Comment: Sorry. I updated the query to correct this. Instead of "select pid" it should be "select cid". The rest of the query should be the same. Also, I did run the same query using the actual table (500 rows more or less) and when running both queries it seems that the connect by query runs a lot slower. Not sure why. Although I noticed that it returns duplicate records rather than a single record as compared to this test table (org).

Answer (score 1):

The hierarchical queries often lead to suboptimal performance. Frequent use of PL/SQL functions *additionally* introduce the problem of *context switch*.

One possible approach to get performance of a hierarchical query comparable with a single row index access is to define a **materialize view** that *pre-calculates* the query.
I’m using the identical data from the @Dr Y Wit answer.

```
create materialized view mv_org as
select  
 CID, PID, NAME, CONNECT_BY_ROOT PID ROOT_PID 
from org0
start with pid in (
select pid from org0
MINUS
select cid from org0
)
connect by prior cid =  pid;
```

Note that the MV contain the original data and adds the column `PID_ROOT` which is the pre-calculated root key.

```
       CID        PID NAME                             ROOT_PID
---------- ---------- ------------------------------ ----------
         2          1 name1########################           1 
         3          2 name2########################           1 
         4          3 name3########################           1
      ....
```

The performance of the queries is fine, as there is no need to do hierarchical query any more.

```
SQL> select pid id
  2  from org0
  3  where connect_by_isleaf = 1
  4  start with cid = 1000000
  5  connect by prior pid = cid;

        ID
----------
         1

Elapsed: 00:00:05.07


SQL> select root_pid from mv_org where cid = 1000000;

  ROOT_PID
----------
         1

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
```

So if you can manage the changes in the hierarchical table in regular windows (say once per day or month) and performs refresh of the MV, you localize the complexity (and performance load) in this refresh and you regular queries are fast.

```
SQL> exec DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH ('mv_org','c');
Elapsed: 00:00:27.58
```